# difference between tty(usb-to-serial) and console driver

Tags: linux, console, driver, tty

i wanted to know what is the difference between a tty driver and a console driver.
I was going through the code of a USB-to- SERIAL driver code..(This can also be used as a console for a embedded target by connecting to a Host pc).. Then why there is a separate driver like "Console " driver.. when a USB-to-SERIAL driver will work ..

Comment: "Console driver" normally means: Use keyboard and screen as TTY. Another meaning of "console driver" could be that this driver is used by the "controlling TTY" of an application. In this case the "console driver" is a higher-level driver that indirectly accesses the USB-to-Serial driver if USB-to-Serial is used as console.